# Not able to install, remove or update anything from software center

Tags: update-manager, mysql, 14.10

I'm having a bad time I guess. Everyday I'm facing new problems. My current problem is - I am not able to install, remove or update anything from software center.

[image]

Also, `sudo apt-get install -f` is throwing error as well.

```
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql', which is also in package mysql-client 5.6.22-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysqlslap', which is also in package mysql-client 5.6.22-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-core-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.6_5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There is something wrong with MYSQL client. But I don't know what or how to fix it. Please help me.

**[Update]**

I'm not able to remove Mysql workbench as well -

[image]

[image]

"sudo dpkg --configure -a" is throwing : dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: I always suggest to (re)install the package wich makes problems manually (fetch it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ) using `sudo dpkg -i whatever.deb` this works pretty fine. By the way(off topic) what kind of Theme is this, looks nice!

Comment: you could also try `--force-bad-version` or something like that see `man dpkg` for more infos

Comment: I had downloaded rpm package for mysql and installed it. But somehow something messed up. This is "Ceti" theme. Took me 1 hour to find this nice theme. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type these commands:

1. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
2. `sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I hope it will help you.

Comment: "sudo dpkg --configure -a" is throwing : dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: Type sudo apt-get update before sudo dpkg --configure -a.

Comment: I did that.. no luck!

Comment: Probably, you would have to remove the dependency packages by typing sudo apt-get purge {dependency_package_name}. Sometimes, these dependency packages will conflict themselves regarding version. I too had the same issue long time ago after executing the above mentioned commands. Finally, got to try with removing the old dependency packages. It might solve you the issue.

Comment: Looks like "sudo apt-get purge mysql-workbench" fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt-get install -f` or `sudo apt-get -f install`. Both are very similar. And dont forget to use `sudo` as `apt-get` requires root priviledges.

Comment: I've already tried that, included in my question.

Comment: In your comment you said you have installed RPM package. How did you manage to do that? Native Ubuntu package system is DEB. RPM will not work here.... and thats what broke your system. Try uninstalling RPM (or just redo last X operations - /var/log/dpkg.log will be of great help here)

Comment: I have used "sudo alien packagename.rpm". From log I can see - "status half-installed mysql-client-core-5.6:amd64 5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2". How to proceed further.